# Scroll up a popup form in Jquery mobile using ios

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I created a form inside a popup using jquery mobile. This is the code of form.

```
 <div data-role="popup" id="popupDetailles" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="b" style="width:100%;" data-transition="pop" class="ui-corner-all ui-popup ui-body-c ui-overlay-shadow" data-dismissible="false">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <form>
        <div style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;" id="header-popup"></h3>
            <hr width="100%" size="2" color="black">

            <h4 style="margin-bottom:0">Type de main doeuvre <span class="style2" style="color: red">*</span></h4>
               <select name="typeMainOeuvre" data-theme="a" id="typeMainOeuvre" required>
                </select>

            <h4 style="margin-bottom:0">Type de temps</h4>
            <select name="typeTemps" data-theme="a" id="typeTemps">
            </select>

            <div id="div_dureeTS">
                <h4 style="margin-bottom:0">Heures de travail</h4>
                <div align="center">
                    <input name="txtDuree" id="txtDuree" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"durationflipbox", "overrideDurationOrder": ["h", "i"], "overrideTimeFormat": 24, "maxDur":85500, "overrideDurationFormat":"%Dl:%DM", "themeButton": "b", "themeInput": "a", "theme": "a", "themeHeader": "a", "hideInput": true, "useInlineBlind":true, "useLang": "fr"}' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="div_dureeTS">
                <h4 style="margin-bottom:0">Heure de début de la journée</h4>
                <div align="center">
                    <input name="txtDebutJournee" id="txtDebutJournee" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"durationflipbox", "overrideDurationOrder": ["h", "i"], "overrideTimeFormat": 24, "maxDur":85500, "overrideDurationFormat":"%Dl:%DM", "themeButton": "b", "themeInput": "a", "theme": "a", "themeHeader": "a", "hideInput": true, "useInlineBlind":true, "useLang": "fr"}' />
                </div>
            </div>


            <h4 style="margin-bottom:0">Frais de stationnement ($)</h4>
            <input name="frais_stationnement" data-theme="a" id="frais_stationnement" type="number" class="classe-frais_stationnement" min='0' max='9999999' onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, this.id)"/>

            <h4 style="margin-bottom:0">Kilométrage (Km)</h4>

            <input name="Kilometrage" data-theme="a" id="Kilometrage"  type="number" class="classe-Kilometrage" min='0' max='9999999' onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, this.id)"/>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="frais_deplacement" name="frais_deplacement"> Inclure frais de déplacement CCQ (65km et plus) 
            </label>

            <h4 style="margin-bottom:0">Commentaire</h4>
            <textarea name="textarea" data-theme="a" id="txtCommentTimeSheet"></textarea>

            <div align="center">
                <button type="button" data-icon="check" data-position="fixed" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" class="buttonBlue" id="btnSaveHeures">Sauvegarder</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

The sumbit button is working in Android devices. But when i try to click on the submit button using iphone, it does'nt work  and jumps me to top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Change your "type" to :

```
<button type="submit" data-icon="check" data-position="fixed" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" class="buttonBlue" id="btnSaveHeures">Sauvegarder</button>
```